# Compare a list in C# to a table in a database

Tags: c#, sql

I need to compare a list of sequential integers created from a C# Windows Form to a database table of integers, indicating if there are duplicates.

I have a version that works, below, but I'm assuming it's probably the least efficient way of doing this - comparing the C# list one by one to each integer in the database table.

Should I get the integers from the database into C#, and then compare?  Or is there a sql way of asking:

if any item in list A is contained in list B, etc.... without comparing each number one-by-one?

I've seen lots of opinions on just looking for 1 item in a database, but I need an efficient way of comparing  C# lists of sometimes 5,000 or more to a database table that can end up having hundreds of thousands of records.

```
public static string VerifyManufacturingSerialOnly(int count, int beginning)
        {
            string duplicateSerials = "";
            int currentSerial = beginning;

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                OleDbConnection connection = BadgeDatabaseDB.GetConnection();
                string checkStatement
                    = "SELECT * "
                    + "FROM SerialNumbersMFG "
                    + "WHERE SerialNumber = @CurrentSerial";
                OleDbCommand command =
                    new OleDbCommand(checkStatement, connection);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CurrentSerial", currentSerial);                

                try
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    OleDbDataReader dataReader =
                        command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SingleRow);
                    if (dataReader.Read())
                    {
                        duplicateSerials +=
                            "Serial # " +
                            currentSerial +
                            " already exists in order # " +
                            dataReader["OrderNumber"].ToString() + "\n";
                    }
                    else {  }
                }
                catch (OleDbException ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }
                finally
                {
                    connection.Close();
                }
                currentSerial++;
                i++;
            }
            return duplicateSerials;
```

Comment: Why not do `Where SerialNumber IN YourCommaDelimitedListofNumbers`? That way you return all the number from the database that match (already exist). Additionally, you shouldn't `Select *` unless you intend to use all the columns returned. Select what is going to be utilized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways:

1. Get all the id's from the database SELECT `SerialNumber FROM SerialNumbersMFG` and then you can use linq `list1.Intersect(list2)`
2. As posted in the comment, most DB have the `IN` clause, so you can use the query like: `SELECTSerialNumber FROM SerialNumbersMFG WHERE SerialNumber IN (1,2,3...)` which will also do the required thing.

Since you mention that the DB can have hundreds of thousand of record I would suggest that second way is better. Please use `stringbuilder` for concatenation.